# Understanding 「心臓麻痺って死因から洗ったのでは 何も出ませんからね」

Tags: translation

From the second episode of *Death Note*, authorities are debating what to do about a bunch of suspected criminals suddenly dying of heart attacks under mysterious circumstances:

> そんな大組織などといったら
>
> FBI か CIA がからんでいるとしか 思えませんな
>
> もう一度言ってみたまえ！
>
> まぁまぁ 冗談は慎んでください
>
> まずはこれが殺人なのか 偶然なのか その解明でしょう
>
> しかし検死の報告では みんな 原因の分からない心臓麻痺でしょ？
>
> **心臓麻痺って死因から洗ったのでは 何も出ませんからね**

I'm confused by what this last bolded sentence means. Here's my attempt to parse it out:

- Does the "心臓麻痺って" mean something like "These /so-called/ heart attacks" (with a hint of skepticism)?
- 死因から洗った I assume means "investigated from the cause of death"? Why is から used instead of を ("investigated the cause of death")?
- Why is のでは used instead of just のは?
- What is 何も出ません getting across?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

心臓麻痺って死因から洗ったのでは何も出ませんからね
＝ 心臓麻痺という死因から調べ始めたのでは、何も手掛かりは出ません（見つかりません）からね

- AってB ＝ AというB ＝ B called A　[link](https://japanese-bank.com/n4/jlpt-n4-tte/)
- 死因から洗った: I guess the person who said it thought that there were other things to be investigated with higher priority and starting an investigation with 死因 was not a good idea. However, I think using を is also OK.

  - 「洗う」can also mean "to investigate". This is used by the police.
- のでは（≠ のは） Usage:「A（assumption） ては / では / のでは、B（something bad）になる」[link](https://chiyo-sampo.net/grammar-jlptn3-teha-deha/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had so many questions about the ~のでは construction that I made a [new, more focused question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/101217/understanding-%e3%81%9f%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%af-conditionals) on it. :)

Comment: So 死因から洗った means "investigating (something), *starting* with the cause of death (and then eventually moving onto other things)"?

Comment: > So 死因から洗った means "investigating (something), starting with the cause of death (and then eventually moving onto other things)"?

Yes!