# Understanding ~たのでは "Conditionals"

Tags: て-form, particle-は, particle-で, conditionals

I recently came across a [sentence containing ~たのでは](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/101207/understanding-%e5%bf%83%e8%87%93%e9%ba%bb%e7%97%ba%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e6%ad%bb%e5%9b%a0%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e6%b4%97%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%af-%e4%bd%95%e3%82%82%e5%87%ba%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%81%ad/101211#101211) I found quite hard to parse, and I wanted to focus more on just its ~たのでは aspect to make a more focused question.

So consider:

> 「彼が**来なかったのでは**、何も始まらない。」

It seems like the best way to parse this sentence is as a conditional:

> **Idiomatic Translation:** If he doesn't come, nothing will start.

**Questions:**

1. Is this sentence *literally* a conditional, or are English speakers just translating it as one to help make sense of it?

> **Literal Translation(?):** As for (は) it being the case that (の) he didn't come, nothing starts.

2. Does ので in these conditionals have anything to do with the ので which is a (more formal) synonym of から?
3. Why is 来る in the past tense, as opposed to the present tense (来ないのでは) or て-form (来なくては)?
4. If this sentence really is a conditional, how does it compare to the various other conditional forms it could be expressed as? Here's my attempt:

   1. **~たら.** 「彼が**来なかったら**、何も始まらない。」
      "If he didn't come, nothing will start." (Places emphasis on the willful action of the person coming or not?)
   2. **~と.**「彼が**来ないと**、何も始まらない。」
      "If he doesn't come, nothing will start." (Almost as if it were a scientific law; sounds weird or hyperbolic in most situations?).
   3. **~えば.**「彼が**来なければ**、何も始まらない。」
      "If he doesn't come, nothing will start." (Not as strong as (2), but still stated more as a dispassionate evaluative or hypothetical fact, and de-emphasizes the act of coming or not as a willful action?)
   4. **のでは.** 「彼が**来なかったのでは**、何も始まらない。」
      "If *it's the case* he didn't come, nothing will start." (places emphasis on "if it's the case case that.." (の)?)

Comment: Isn't this just "in the case that XYZ..."?  As in, not a conditional, but more a supposition / hypothetical?  It parses out to me as regular nominalization with の, followed by では (functionally the same as ～ては on verb stems). Consider also constructions like 「XYZしてはだめです」, where the XYZする is presented as a supposition -- "in the case that XYZ happens / in the case that you do XYZ,, it is bad" → "don't do XYZ".

Comment: のでは being analyzed as (explanatory-の)+(て-form of だ)+(contrastive は) makes sense. But can't all of the Japanese conditionals be used to present hypothetical scenarios? Perhaps the thing that distinguishes のでは is that it places more emphasis on the "result" of the hypothetical being bad?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Do you know why 来なかった is placed in the past tense before のでは (as opposed to the present tense 来ないのでは or て-form 来なくては without a の)?

Comment: I don't, no. The link in your original post goes to another JSE thread that doesn't include the phrase 「来なかったのでは」 anywhere, so I have no other context. Guessing, I'd say that the event is (or is supposed to be) in the past.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Sorry, the sentence in the linked thread is different from "来なかったのでは...", but it does use the past-tense "~たのでは" construction.

With that said, I just found [another thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/100094/51280) where naruto says that ~たのでは implies that the preceding clause has in fact already happened. If that's true, 来なかったのでは wouldn't actually be a hypothetical, and the whole sentence would mean something like "*Given (は) it's actually the case (ので) that he didn't come* (来なかったのでは), nothing is starting." Does that make sense to you?

Comment: [では](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF/#jn-152205) is a compound particle and means 判断の前提. Analyzing further is just overanalyzing, even if that's etymologically the case.